Display query parameter example in Swagger UI
Here is a simple API spec:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/HITESHWALIA_1/simple-api/1.0.0
In Swagger UI, is there any way to display query parameter example?  That is, to display GET /hello?name=John

If you expand the operation, "John" is displayed in the input field of the name parameter. That's how Swagger UI displays parameter example values.
